# Remove tag but leave contents - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a bit tired tonight and just can't really think how to do this simply. Basically, I have something similar to the below and I want to strip out html tags but leave their contents:

```
<a href="#">some content</a> and more <a href="#"> and more content</a>
```

and actually return the following:

```
some content and more and more content
```

Any help as always - massively appreciated!

**EDIT:** Thank you all so much for the answers - there I was going down the regular expression route, way to over complicate things! I actually ended up using .text() as suggested below, I've used this before but only to set, never to retrieve and it worked better as I was returning quite a large object! Thank you so much for all the suggestions :). I'll accept the answer after 6 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(selector).text() should strip out all the html.

Comment: Never knew this method stripped out the tags by default! I've only ever used it to set text, or retrieve plain text, thank you so much for opening my mind!

Answer (score 11):

[`$(`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`'a'`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)[`)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)[`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQyLk/)

Answer (score 2):

This way is a little longer but maybe more self explanatory than the `contents()` method.

```
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html())
})
```

`replaceWith` accepts replacement html. (not selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
$(...).find('*')
      .replaceWith(function() { return this.childNodes });
```

I don't know how well this will handle nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.stripTags = function() {
    return this.replaceWith( this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') );
```

};

Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg18843.html