# How to remove html tag and just leave text in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I see a similar case which answer my question in JQuery way:
[Remove tag but leave contents - jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037085/remove-tag-but-leave-contents-jquery-javascript)

But I need to know how C# works for this? Is there any API in C# that I can use to strip out the tag and leave the plane text?

From:

```
<a href="#">some content</a> and more <a href="#"> and more content</a>
```

To:

```
some content and more and more content
```

Thanks.

Comment: HTMLAgilityPack .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: You could also look into Regex

Comment: @TGH yes, I know Regex can do this, but I want to know is there already any best practise for this?

Comment: @m.hasan , your answer is good to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use HtmlAgilityPack ( http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ ), load your HTML document into a `HtmlDocument` instance and query `document.DocumentNode.InnerText`.